# How to set default theme in unix command-line

Tags: unix, gnome-terminal

I have decided to learn bash. I am using a mac.
In terminal (built in mac version of unix command line) is there a way to set the default theme to homebrew or other? thank you!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try [unix.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Preferences panel of the terminal application, select the Themes tab, choose Homebrew and click on default.